# VirtualBox port forwarding not working (HTTP: no, ssh: yes)

Tags: virtualbox

I have VirtualBox 4.3.26(newest as for now) in Win7, and a guest CentOS7.
I enabled port forwarding for SSH and HTTP

I can ssh into guest from host use putty by `ssh 127.0.0.1:2222`, but I cannot access guest web server from host by `http://127.0.0.1:3000`

## Host:

```
NIC 1:           MAC: 08002764D472, Attachment: NAT, Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
NIC 1 Settings:  MTU: 0, Socket (send: 64, receive: 64), TCP Window (send:64, receive: 64)
NIC 1 Rule(0):   name = Rule 1, protocol = tcp, host ip = 0.0.0.0, host port = 2222, guest ip = 0.0.0.0, guest port = 22
NIC 1 Rule(1):   name = Rule 2, protocol = tcp, host ip = 0.0.0.0, host port = 3000, guest ip = 0.0.0.0, guest port = 3000
```

netstat

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:3000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

curl(cygwin)

```
$ curl -vv http://127.0.0.1:3000
* Rebuilt URL to: http://127.0.0.1:3000/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.41.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:3000
> Accept: */*
>
* Recv failure: Connection was reset
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset
```

## guest

netstat

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                             -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                             2743/node
```

curl is ok

Comment: "I cannot access guest web server from host by http://127.0.0.1:3000" What specifically happens when you try? Do you get an error message? What does the error say? Could you run `netstat` on the host and edit your question to include the relevant lines for the forwarded ports?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same symptoms with a Centos 7 guest and a Windows 10 host. Turned out the firewall on the guest was the problem.

Problem was solved after:

```
sudo systemctl stop firewalld
```